# Style collapsed navbar in Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

How do I style a navbar in Bootstrap when it has been collapsed and then opened via the toggle button?  It doesn't look like bootstrap adds a class to the navbar when the menus are collapsed into the button.  It seems like there should a class that is present when the navbar is in expanded/collapsed mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course I found the answer right after I ask the question...  When the hamburger button is pressed, bootstrap changes

```
<div id="main-menu" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
```

to

```
<div id="main-menu" class="navbar-collapse collapse in">
```

so,

```
.collapse.in ... {}
```

targets rules in the expanded state.